# Issue in converting Timetstamp format

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, timestamp

In my data frame I have a column which contains timestamps. Now these timestamps are in the format(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) and I want to change them to (dd--mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss). I have tried to do so but only the first row is changing properly and the rest of the rows are converting to epoch time i think.

**Snapshot of Dataframe**

[image: Click here for Snapshot of Dataframe]

**what I tried**

[image: Click here to see what I tried]

**the other way I tried**

[image: Click to see the other way I tried]

As you can see only the first row is changing whereas the other rows are not. Please help guys!!!

Comment: Please do not use screenshots to show your code, you should make the effort of pasting the code directly into your question.

Comment: I am sorry about that will do so from now on.

Comment: You can start now by editing this question - it makes it easier for us to help you if we can copy the code and try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe is because of the data type of your column in pandas. If you want to follow your previous attempts, you could just create a new column and fill the data as a string like this:

```
df_sch["UTC Formatted"] = [datetime.datetime.strftime(entity, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M%S") for entity in df_sch["UTC"]]
```

In this sense the data will be stored as string! Hope this helps!

Comment: Good to know! Good luck with your project! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this instruction:

```
df_sch['UTC'] = df_sch["UTC"].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

This will convert all UTC column values in your dataframe with the wanted format

Comment: Hi I tried doing this but the dates remained in the same format only                               0    2020-02-29 18:30:00
1    2020-02-29 18:45:00
2    2020-02-29 19:00:00

Comment: Did you put "df_sch['UTC'] =" before the instruction? new values must be assigned

Comment: Yes I did that only but still the output is in the old format only

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I edited my answer, please try now

Comment: Now its working perfectly, thanks for your help:-)))

Comment: Glad to help you